Google Cloud // Cloud Storage / Como conectar DB csv guardado en bucket a script de jupyterlab
He creado un cluster en GCP para trabajar con PySpark. Ya subí un notebook actividad1.ipynb y el archivo flights_act1.csv a la carpeta CGS de Jupyterlab, he intentado conectar al notebook la base de datos pero no lo he logrado. Este es el código usado:
ruta_hdfs = "hdfs://unircluster-m:9092/ippmd/notebooks/jupyter/flights_act1.csv"
flightsDF = spark.read\
 .format("csv")\
 .option("header", "true")\
 .option("inferSchema", "true")\
 .option("delimiter", ",")\
 .load("hdfs://unircluster-m:9092/ippmd/notebooks/jupyter/flights_act1.csv")

flightsDF.show()

Pero no funcionó.
Podría alguien por favor indicarme como se debe enlazar.
Les agradezco.
